# Al intentar exportar bases de datos en PHPMyAdmin, dice descargar un archivo SQL y luego aparece "failed". ¿Cómo corregirlo?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Tengo unas pocas bases de datos en phpmyadmin las cuales requiero de exportar. Cada vez que le doy al botón de continuar desde el apartado de exportar, simplemente no lo realiza, me "descarga un archivo SQL" pero realmente dice *failed*, o sea que no se descargó. No sé cómo solucionarlo.

Estoy utilizando la última versión de XAMPP, con PHP 8.1.5.

¿Alguna idea?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Intenta con una versión estable anterior. Ese tipo de error generalmente es por alguna incompatibilidad con tu equipo.

Comment: ¿Cuál es tu versión de PHPMyAdmin? Ciertas versiones tienen problemas de incompatibilidad con PHP 8. Ahora bien, PHPMyAdmin no es otra cosa que una interfaz para interactuar con la Base de Datos (además bastante lenta para mi gusto). Prueba a crear un dump de tu base de datos desde la consola y no tendrás ningún problema. Tendrás que teclear un poco en la Terminal, pero verás rápido la diferencia en cuanto a rapidez y demás.

Comment: @A.Cedano creo que ya lo he solucionado

Comment: ¿Es lo mismo que [este problema](/q/523354/)?

Comment: @padaleiana en mi respuesta, en el primer enlace le he puesto la misma pregunta pero sin marcar, lo malo que al no estar marcada con el check en verde no se cuenta como duplicada porque ya me ha pasado de reportar una pregunta duplicada y no dejarme por que no estaba marcada como resuelta, de todos modos le puede ayudar esa pregunta a resolver ese problema :-)

Comment: @JavierG.Raya Igual podés reportarla cuando la otra pregunta no tiene respuestas aceptadas. Lo que no podés hacer es relacionarla como duplicada de una pregunta _sin responder_. Acá está la [referencia](/help/duplicates).

Comment: vale muchas gracias @padaleiana

Comment: La verdad, no lo he solucionado, encontré que a travez de la terminal se puede exportar, pero el sql generado me trae las tables y algunas views, pero mis store procedures no los trae

Comment: Eso es porque `mysqldump` trae por defecto incluir los TRIGGER pero no las STORE PROCEDURES / FUNCTIONS, por tanto, si las quieres incluir tienes que indicarlo en el comando, incluyendo la bandera **`--routines`** en el comando. Para más detalles revisa el [Manual de Referencia](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump-stored-programs.html).

Comment: Cómo puedo marcar la respuesta de @A. Cedano como correcta?, Además de eso, sabe que otra propiedad se puede escribir en la terminal para que me exporte los datos también?

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con que *te exporte los datos*? ¿Puedes mostrar el comando que estás intentando? Cualquier duda sobre `mysqldump`, puedes consultar el [Manual de Referencia](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html).

Comment: Vale, no habia notado que con el comando .\mysqldump -h localhost -uroot -p --routines --triggers --events db_name > C:\path... se puede exportar la base de datos con sus views.. store procedures y datos adicionalmente, como puedo marcar como correcta tu respuesta?

Comment: Ahora te escribo una respuesta ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ciertas versiones de phpMyAdmin tienen [problemas de compatibilidad con PHP 8](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/16746).

Ahora bien, phpMyAdmin no es otra cosa que una interfaz para interactuar con la Base de Datos (además bastante lenta para mi gusto).

Podrías intentar crear un dump de tu base de datos desde la consola. Ciertamente no tendrás una interfaz gráfica, pero sabiendo qué comando tienes que ejecutar no hay ningún problema. Además, una copia de base de datos puede ser una tarea costosa (sobre todo si la base de datos es enorme). Si lo haces desde la consola será mucho más rápido.

Por ejemplo:

```
mysqldump -h localhost -uroot -p --routines --triggers --events db_name > C:\path...
```

Según el [Manual de Referencia](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump-stored-programs.html), `mysqldump` sólo trae por defecto incluir los `TRIGGER`, si quieres las stored procedure tienes que poner la bandera **`--routines`** y si quieres los eventos tienes que poner la bandera **`--events`**. Si no pones esas banderas, no obtendrás ni SP ni eventos en el resultado.

Para más detalles sobre `mysqldump` consulta su [documentación en el Manual de Referencia](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html).